# Creating an App Engine instance for Mobile Cloud Backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Relatively new to the android dev world. I downloaded the mobile backend starter project and got everything working; modified it for my needs and it's still working. This is all in Eclipse.
I'm in the process of connecting to a Cloud SQL instance and the preferred way seems to be to enable Cloud SQL in the App Engine project.
I don't have an App Engine project, and when I create one (setting the configuration for my application etc.), I got enormous amounts of errors.
Before I troubleshoot them, I wanted to ask:

1. Can I create an App Engine Project instance for an existing android client app?
2. If so, will the app engine project instance correctly reference my app engine instance online?

Thank you for any detailed reponses.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions for extending the gae mobile backend

https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/extend_backend

That should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I actually did follow that tutorial at one point and it still didn't get to me to where I want. I have everything working now though. I just started from scratch and copy-pasted my way back to app heaven. I'll be writing a tutorial on Cloud SQL with Android soon as this was a major headache for me.